# addPicture method of XWPFRun of Apache POI does not work

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

I want to add an image to a new word document but when I run the program I get this error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlToken$Factory`

After I added the xmlbean library to my pom.xml and got the following error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/schema/DocumentFactory`

I leave my code

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();   
XWPFParagraph title = doc.createParagraph();   
XWPFRun run = title.createRun();
run.addPicture(new ByteArrayInputStream(a), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, bar.getTitle().getText(), Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200));
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.write(out);
```

and the apache POI dependecies that I use

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
         <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
         <artifactId>poi-ooxml-full</artifactId>
         <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
         <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
         <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If I remove the xmlbean dependency I get the first error, otherwise the second. Is it a problem of version 5.0.0 of apache POI?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you mixing different versions of poi? 5.2.2, 5.0.0 ???

Comment: Don't mix different versions of `apache poi`. The `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.2` does not fit to `poi-ooxml-5.0.0`. Also `xmlbeans-3.1.0` does not fit. See https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components. Using `maven` dependencies `<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>` and `<artifactId>poi</artifactId>` should be enough. All other should be pulled automatically as needed.

Comment: I have tried putting the same version and the error continues

Comment: `xmlbeans` also needs to fit. It needs to be `xmlbeans-4.0.0` for `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0` and `xmlbeans-5.0.3` for `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.2`.

Comment: I have put the versions that you have told me and it has given me the following error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream`, I add the dependency of `commons-io-2.11.0` and it works. Thanks for your help